# Should I use the same values for database, serial and crlnumber in the config for a Root-CA and its Sub-CA?

Tags: ssl, openssl

Should I use the same files for `database`, `serial` and `crlnumber` in the `ca_default`-section of my config file for both the Root CA and the subordinate CA? Or is it better to use different sets of files?

If both is possible, what would be the advantages and drawbacks of the variants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL is not a good option for a CA - it even says so in the `man` [pages](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ca.html).

You should consider the Root CA and the subordinate as completely separate entities, otherwise there's no point in having the sub CA.  Your Root CA should be offline, and the subordinate should be in routine use.

Now that you're running two separate CAs, it stands to reason that those files will not be shared.

You should also consider the purpose of those files.  The Root CA only issues a CA certificate to the subordinate CA.  That means that its `database` will have one entry in it (until you renew the CA certificate or stand up another subordinate), while the subordinate CA will have all the end-entity certificates in its `database`.

The `serial` file keeps a tab on the serial numbers of certificates, therefore the subordinate CA's `serial` file will have counted much further than the Root CA's.

Similarly, the Root CA issues CRLs much less often than the subordinate CA (as it trusts the operator of the sub CA much more than the sub CA trusts its end-entities), therefore the values in the `crlnumber` files will also diverge.

So the advantage of using different files is that OpenSSL will work, while you'll probably confuse it (and yourself) if you try to share files.

Comment: Thank you! I already planned to separate those files, but did not understand why so many tutorials on the net do it differently.